# ExpressJS response middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've made an HttpInterceptor for the front-end that send every request with some default headers and automatically encrypt body/url for every request and a middleware for the back-end that check the headers and decrypt the packet if needed.. Now I have a problem with the response middleware, because I want to send the response with encrypted body only for some requests.

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{

    if(req.headers['x-data-encoded'] && (req.headers['x-server'] == "HP")){

        res.append('X-Encoded-Data', true);

        var nsp = res.send;

        res.send = function(data){
            var body = Crypto.encodeData(data); // Result a string of letters and numbers
            nsp.apply(this, body);
        }

    }

    next();
});
```

**Caught exception: TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object**

Comment: Where is this error thrown? It looks like it's not in the code you show.

Comment: It doesn't show me the line but if I comment the 'nsp' and the 'res.send' function it work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that error appears because send method waits an object and it is receiving a String. If you assign manually body an object this error should dissapear or change to another one.

Besides, second parameter of apply should be an array.

Hope it helps

Comment: `nsp.apply(this, {packet: body});` Doesn't throw an error but the request has no response data available..

Comment: Second parameter of apply should be an array. Probably is because of that

Comment: Thank you very much! The module is working well now. `.apply(this, [body]);`